# Load React application with a given Redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to avoid clicking through a large frontend application to get to the component I need to make changes to.

I am wondering if I could save the redux store and reload my application after each code change with that given store object. Is this possible with a React/Redux based application?

Comment: you can use `localstorage` or from database by calling `api` with `redux-thunk`

Comment: @adel Do you mean I should get the store object from which I would like to start my application, save it to localstorage and when the application reloads I should set the initial state to the one read from localstore?

Comment: yep exactly try checking if `localStorage ` is set if it's retrieve it !

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but I was curious how others would solve this issue. Anyway, thanks, I will do just that.

Comment: well there is another approach you can do with read and write file by creating a `json` file that hold your `initialstate ` and then write the new state to this file. you can do it using `Node.js` file system

Comment: If you are talking about making a change to a component, and then have the browser refresh only that code change, then you should look into webpack and hot module reloading. This means you can retain your state as is, and only the component code will update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can save set the store with initial values. Initial values can be passed as the second argument to createstore api.

For more details: https://redux.js.org/api/createstore

Comment: The question was rather about how I can persist the redux store across application reloads. I will edit the question to emphasize this.

Comment: Saving and retrieving from localstorage is what i did.